# Issue inputing data, python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

So I'm working on a project for school, I've created my database and its working, I've inputed data the traditional way with in insert into statement and then the data, I'm now trying to get it so that my user can input the data. The error I'm getting is that it will not let the user input their data for the first question.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('agile.db')
c = conn.cursor()[enter image description here][1]
story1 = str(input("What is your story? "))
points1 = int(input("How many points is this story? "))
done1 = input('Is your task complete? ')
x = '''INSERT INTO stories(story, points, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?));'''
c.execute(x,(story1, points1, done1,))
conn.commit()
```

The image below shows the error:

[image: img]

Comment: Please review the edits made to the post, it looks like the image was removed.  Also it would be helpful to see the error within the question instead of as a linked image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and that you say it's erroring in the first input, it may be related to how you are typing your string.

Try this out

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('agile.db')

c = conn.cursor()

#May want to add functionality to verify data type
story1 = input("What is your story? ")

#May want to add functionality to verify data type
points1 = input("How many points is this story? ")

#May want to add functionality to verify data type
done1 = input('Is your task complete? ')


sql_cmd = 'INSERT INTO stories(story, points, done) VALUES ({}, {}, {});'.format(story1, points1, done1)
c.execute(sql_cmd)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: So I've made those changes and it is still giving me the same error on the first input.

Comment: Please post the input you are typing as well as the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and for me everything seems to work (at least for the first two questions)
I assume the problem is with your python installation. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.4

Comment: I am using python 2.7,  but I do not think it is just a version problem. In any case, try to reinstall python. I recommend using anaconda. https://www.anaconda.com/download/